# Updating a cell in DataGrid using C#.net

Tags: c#, datagrid, datagridview

I found ListView very slow for my program. Therefore i decided to move to DataGrid.

Before this, I only used to list the data from database source.

I used following code to add new row to the DataGrid:

```
        DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
        row.CreateCells(MyGrid);  
        row.Cells[0].Value = "1";  
        MyGrid.Rows.Add(row);
        row.Cells["Category"].Value = "Vegetables";
        row.Cells["Item"].Value = "Carrot";
        row.Cells["Price"].Value = "12.50";
```

I've used similar pattern to add new row for different things. Also let me know if there is any better method to directly add variables to the database.

The main thing i wanted to know is how to edit the cell data.

For example I have following data table:

```
ID    ITEM     Price
1    item A     100
2    item B     120
3    item C     121
4    item D     103
```

And I want to change the price value of **item B** from "**120**" to "**210**".
 how can i achieve this?

In ListView i looked for column with value **item B** and get the column index of price and replaced the value. How can i do same in DataGrid.

I am using C#.net

Additional note:
   The list generated is a dynamic list there for I'll need to find the cell with value item **B** and then change the value of **price column** of respective row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Create your custom DataTable

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id",typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Item",typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Price",typeof(decimal));
dt.AcceptChanges(); // This is the point, where you can change dataTable items.
```

and add your items to your DataTable rows like:

```
foreach(var rowItem in blabla)
{
object[] row = new object[]
{
rowItem.Id,
rowItem.Item,
rowItem.Price
};
dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

and then bind dataTable to gridView

```
gridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

and now changes made on gridView will update your DataTable too :)

Comment: will this make datas in DataGridView appear slower? Thank you very much for the code.. I got the clue :)

Comment: @HackTweaks How much data? :)

Comment: about 500 rows... how can i compare the item value? It would have been much more convenient if I could just search for ITEM B and change the value of PRICE in same ROW... As we do with list view.

Comment: with 500 rows you wont reduce performance. The changes will be made on gridView. and gridView is equals your DataTable. So you can search changed parameter with ID (if ID is unique)

Answer (score 0):

Why can you not bind your data object list to the Datagrid, and after you have just to modify the data object list and it's done!